# Nhibernate unique constraint FK object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, constraints

I have a class with multiple subclasses

```
public class BaseClass{}
public class SubClass : BaseClass 
{
   public SomeClass someClass { get; set; }
}
```

I have an other class `SomeClass` which has a unique constraint which will be often violated through creating a new class.
And thats what i want to do:

```
SubClass toBeSaved = new SubClass(){
   someClass = new SomeClass("UniqueConstraintForSomeClass")
};
session.Save(toBeSaved );
```

How can i prevent a UniqueConstraintFailed Except and my someclass in the DB will be loaded into the someclass in my `toBeSaved` object. Is there a way to do that?

I tried to write a unique save method for each `SubClass` but I didnt get that to work when I call it from the baseclass. Something like: `InsertIntoDb((BaseClass) SubClass)`, but I THINK that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For saving now the baseClass I use the visitor pattern.
So I send the BaseClass my Visitor and he is saving all the Subclasses. So I can configure my constraints and how they are saved in the Visitor.
I found a nice post about this pattern on http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/991